# Multiple emails input not working

Tags: php, email, implode

I have a referral page where people can put in email addresses to send referrals out.

```
<form action="referemails.php" method="post">
Insert your friend's email below to refer them!<br><br>
Email: <input type="email" id="referemail" name="referemail[]" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="example@email.com"><br>
Email: <input type="email" id="referemail" name="referemail[]" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="example@email.com"><br>
Email: <input type="email" id="referemail" name="referemail[]" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="example@email.com"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

The code for sending the emails are as follows:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['referemail'])) {
    $username= $_SESSION['username'];
    $options = array("options" => array(FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY));
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'referemail', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, $options);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg = '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>'; };

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: example@email.com' . "\r\n";
                        $to  = implode(',', $email);
                        $subject = 'Email!';
                        $message ='...';}

                           if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
                               header('Location: ../includes/referfriends.php');
}
?>
```

I've tried a couple variations of the `implode(','` command. But either I'm not putting it in the right spot or, my theory, is that my filters on the $email is not letting multiple emails. It will send out the email if there is only one email address entered, but multiple emails it acts like it sent out though it didn't, and I get no errors in my log.
What did I miss or misplace that's blocking the multiple addresses? Thanks in advance for any knowledge or helpful links. I've tried searching the webz and tried multiple options but always get to this point.

Comment: Usually multiple email addresses should be delimited using the semi-colon character(;).  Maybe validate the input to ensure ";" is used as a delimiter, or change "," to ";" on submit.

Comment: @JohnieKarr Not in mail(), they use a comma.

Comment: implode is used with array `implode(",", $array)` but from what i can see  from your code your `$to` variable is not array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your variable `$email`, and by extension `$to`, is a string. Therefore implode will not work as that is designed for arrays.

You've used the `multiple` tag on your input, but that is for use with files, not text inputs. You  need to rethink how you are getting e-mail addresses.

If you want to get multiple e-mail addresses you need multiple inputs like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email[]">
<input type="email" name="email[]">
```

Notice the square brackets, that allows multiple inputs to have the same name and submit as an array.

You can then use the following to get the data on your sending page:

```
$options = array("options" => array(FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY));
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, $options);
```

`$email` will then hold an array of the submitted e-mail addresses.

Comment: hmm. i see. I didn't know multiple was just for files. I'll review my work and see what I come up with. Thanks.

Comment: @KissingKings Check my updated answer for how to submit input arrays.

Comment: what is the `"options"` in your `array("options"` from?

Comment: @KissingKings Those are standard options available for use with `filter_input`. Check out [filter flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) for more info.

Comment: I see. Well I changed the question above to reflect your suggestions. If I understood what you were saying correctly that is. Now I can't send emails to a single address though, let alone multiple. But thank you for your assistance thus far.

Comment: @KissingKings that's because you haven't updated your second check. Add `$options` on the end of that too so you have `$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, $options);`, although I'm not sure if you can use `FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY` with `filter_var`. If not you will have to loop through each variable in the array and test them individually.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed my php code removing the filters completely. In place of

```
$options = array("options" => array(FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY));
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'referemail', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, $options);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Not a valid email
    $error_msg = '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>'; };
```

I simply put:

```
$email = implode(",",$_REQUEST['referemail']);
```

and it works.